# Unable to get Neo4j to run

Tags: neo4j

I searched for an answer to this, but was unable to find anyone else having the same problem.

- This is the first time I've tried to use Neo4j.
- I'm running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.
- I downloaded and unzipped Neo4j Community 1.8.2 for Windows.
- In a command window, I switched to the bin folder and ran Neo4j.bat.
- I received the following message in the command window: **Unable to locate jvm. Could not find HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment/CurrentVersion entry in windows registry.**
- I verified that I have the latest JVM.
- I verified that the above registry key is *not* present in the location shown, but I did find it at HKLM\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment/CurrentVersion.

How should I proceed?

Thanks for any direction!

Comment: What version do you have? What does this produce on the command line: java -version

Comment: I resolved the issue before I saw your comment, so I don't know what that command would have said. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed JRE version 6 on my machine and this cleared the problem. (I previously had version 7 on the machine.)

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed this problem by making a new environment variable JAVA_HOME and pointing it to my Java installation folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

Answer (score 0):

try to set up the java PATH variable to the correct path. tutorial here:
http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

than, newest java are i think by 2 version newer than the original java for neo4j 1.8.2. a remind myself some problems with such versioning few months ago - i solved it by running neo4j in the newest versions of 1.9.0x

Comment: Before resolving the issue, I tried adding the JRE (v7) bin path to the Windows path variable, and this had no effect. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the JAVA_HOME path in your environment variables.